# get a specific line from in linux using grep

Tags: unix, shell, shell-scripting, grep, awk

Hello I am new to linux and grep and awk commands.

I am trying to get the number value from this string variable and then store it in another variable.

```
var1="Version must be incremented on update. Current version is: 532"
var2=var1 | grep "?"
```

What should I do in order to only retrieve val 532 from the above string and store it in var2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$var1` to reference it, rather than `var1`. You need to `echo` it so that Bash won't try to run it as a program. You [should put double-quotes around it as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells).

For grep, you need a regular expression to match the numbers, lots of patterns might work but I'm using ["*one or more digits, at the end of the string*"](https://regex101.com/r/eIFDOF/1), and you need the grep option `-o` to print only the matching text, instead of the whole line.

Run this inside `$()` to stop the shell trying to run the result as a program, and your code looks like this:

```
var1="Version must be incremented on update. Current version is: 532"
var2=$(echo "$var1" | grep '[0-9]\+$' -o)
echo "$var2"
# 532
```